# Array formula to also get most recent comment?

Tags: google-sheets

Worksheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13o5d1AhslmYP3BcO1U16DxkyoCxo44rt7wgOKcq-PeE/edit#gid=0

I have a table layout above where I am utilizing a drop down filter in A20 and B20 to match the tables above to provide me the headers below those drop downs:

[image]

Calc I used in A23:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(FILTER({VLOOKUP(FILTER(A2:A11,C2:C11=A21),A2:B11, 
{1,2},FALSE),VLOOKUP(FILTER(A2:A11&B21,C2:C11=A21),{I2:I10&J2:J10,J2:J10,L2:L10- 
K2:K10},{2,3},FALSE),VLOOKUP(FILTER(A2:A11&B21,C2:C11=A21), 
{E2:E11&J2:J10,F2:F11},2,FALSE)},VLOOKUP(FILTER(A2:A11&B21,C2:C11=A21), 
{I2:I10&J2:J10,J2:J10},2,FALSE)=B21)))
```

As you can see, in the green table the latest comment for ID 1011 is "Buyer about to sign" but it's still pulling in the comment before that?

Comment: please share a link to the sheet in the screenshot so we don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @z.. My apologies, added link above the post with editor access

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(id_, filter(A2:A15,C2:C15=A21),
     status_, filter({I2:I15,xlookup(I2:I15,A2:A15,B2:B15,),J2:J15,L2:L15-K2:K15},xmatch(I2:I15,id_),J2:J15=B21),
     hstack(status_,index(xlookup(status_,E2:E15,F2:F15,,,-1))))
```

[image]